# CRM 2013: Supported way to display dialogs

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

What is the supported way to display an HTML webresource as a dialog ?

I have tried `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource(webResourceName)` but it's displayed as a webpage

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by a 'dialog'? As in a CRM 2011 dialog? What else would you expect OpenWebResource to do?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the only way to open your webresource in dialog mode is to use showModalDialog method of window. Check following url please - [showModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to display webpages inside a dialog in CRM 2013, as per my knowledge that is not possible.

However, in order to simulate what you're trying to achieve, you could design the entire dialog in HTML itself (having buttons like Next, and pages, etc.) and then display the HTML page as a popup using OpenWebResource. You can make use of the REST api of CRM to carry out the CRUD operations during the dialog progress.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#BKMK_OpenWebResource)?  You can control the width and height if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know this is fairly old, but wanted to add my $0.02. It allows you to specify the height and width, but it seems to ignore it and open the page in a new tab every time. It's possible I'm missing something, but for the life of me it won't work with a size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Xrm.Internal.openDialog(address, settingsobject, null, null, return function)

var settingsobject=new Xrm.DialogOptions;
settingsobject.height = 420;
settingsobject.width = Xrm.Page.context.client.getClient() === Xrm.ClientNames.mobile ? 500 : 450;
```

Comment: Thanks alot, however this is not documented in the MSDN so are you sure it's supported ?

Comment: Definitely not supported. It's frustrating.